# Одна entity для двух таблиц в hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Имеется две таблицы с одинаковым именем table, которые находятся в разных базах(для удобства буду называть их Table1 и Table2)
Table1 имеет следующие колонки - COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B ,COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D (типы не важны).
Table2 - это копия table1, но в ней усеченный набор колонок (только COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B).

Подключаемся к базе из java + hibernate.
В java есть entity (опускаю все лишнее) -

```
@Table(name = "TABLE")
public class Table {

   @Column(name = "COLUMN_A")
   private String columnA;

   @Column(name = "COLUMN_B")
   private String columnB;

   @Column(name = "COLUMN_C")
   private String columnC;

   @Column(name = "COLUMN_D")
   private String columnD;
```

Если мы выполним селект к table1, где все эти поля есть, то все смаппиться нормально.
Если выполняем селект к table2 используя эту сущность, то получим ошибку.

```
ORA-00904 "TABLE"."COLUMN_C": недопустимый идентификатор
```

Это логично, так как хибер выполнит селект в котором перечислит все поля из entity, которых по факту нет в базе `SELECT COLUMN_A ,COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C, COLUMN_D FROM TABLE;`

Это можно решить созданием отдельной сущности для table2, но кажется, что можно решить это иначе.

Решение, которое бы также подошло заключается в выполнении селекта типа `SELECT * FROM TABLE`, но в HQL нет  оператора `*`
Подскажите, можно ли как то решить эту проблему не прибегая к созданию отдельной сущности?

Comment: Даже, если вы это сделаете - это не поможет, так как следующая проблема будет в том, что хибернейт будет пробовать достать колонки `COLUMN_C` и `COLUMN_D` чтоб присвоить значения полям `columnC` и `columnD` в объектах. Вы пробуете сделать то, что хибернейт не умеет.

Comment: Не понимаю. Если я сделаю отдельную сущность где будут только 
COLUMN_A и COLUMN_B
То все сработает. Но не хочется создавать отдельную сущность для этого